# Can i create serial number for invoice

Tags: sql, string, oracle, recursive-query

Can i create serial number for invoice from oracle table

table:

```
ID YEAR  LAST_VALUE
ABC 2020  900
DEF 2020  500
GHI 2020  250
```

With this tabel i want create a list like thiss

```
ABC2020001
ABC2020002
.
.
ABC2020900

DEF2020001
DEF2020002
.
.
DEF2020500

GHI2020001
GHI2020002
.
.
GHI2020250
```

Answer (score 3):

One option uses a recursive query to generate the number series:

```
with cte (id, yr, last_val, val) as (
    select id, yr, last_val, 1 from mytable
    union all
    select id, yr, last_val, val + 1 from cte where val < last_val
)
select id || yr || to_char(val, 'fm0000') serial_number from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=aef6f214de5f98128ae3c7e03e93f343)**

Comment: Thanks for answer but i must get ID number from oracle database

Comment: @acar6783: well, that's what the query does... It assumes that your table is called `mytable`.

Comment: sorgu = " select SERI,YIL,SIRA, 1 from SYS20.EATT001 Union all " & _
    " select SERI,YIL,SIRAl, val + 1 from cte where val < SIRA) " & _
"select SERI|| YIL || to_char(val, 'fm0000') serial_number from cte order by SERI, val"

Answer (score 2):

All you need is lateral. That's all. It's always good to mention your Oracle version whenever you post your question on any forum (The below solution requires at least 12c). The below is what you need. By the way, last_value is an analytical function and the same name cannot be used as column name. So, I have used lastvalue.

```
select * from data,
lateral
(
 select id||year||to_char(level,'fm000') as new_id
 from dual
 connect by level <= lastvalue
)
```

Comment: Nice use of `lateral` with a row generator. Also (now that I check) `cross apply` does the same thing without the comma join. https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/lateral-inline-views-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-joins-12cr1

Comment: Yes, it does. But I prefer using lateral, as it gives a look of Oracle's old way of joining tables with comma separation.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative,

We can do it by using `connect by` and by casting to type `sys.odcinumberlist` to generate the series using a start and end point.

```
with data 
as
(
select 'ABC' id,2020 year,900 lastvalue,1 firstvalue
from dual
union all 
select 'DEF', 2020, 500,1 from dual
union all 
select 'GHI', 2020, 250,1 from dual
)
select id||year||
       lpad((firstvalue + 
             series.column_value - 1)
           ,length(lastvalue)
           ,'0'
           )invoicenumber
  from data
      ,table(cast(multiset
             (select level
                from dual
              connect by level <= lastvalue-firstvalue + 1) 
              as sys.odcinumberlist)) series
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you have a table in your Oracle database named `SerialNumbers` with 2 fields, `SerialNumber` as some sort of string type and Used as a Oracle's interpretation of a Boolean.

We fill a `Datatable` with your serial numbers and then send them off to Oracle.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("SerialNumber", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Used", GetType(Boolean))
    Dim letters = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "HIJ", "KLM", "NOP", "QRS", "TUV", "WXY"}
    For Each LetterGroup In letters
        For i = 1 To 900
            Dim sn = LetterGroup & i.ToString.PadRight(3, "0"c)
            dt.Rows.Add(sn, False)
        Next
    Next
    Using cn As New OracleConnection(ConStr),
            da As New OracleDataAdapter("Select SerialNumber,Used From SerialNumbers;", cn)
        Dim cb As New OracleCommandBuilder(da)
        da.Update(dt)
    End Using
End Sub
```

When you need a new SerialNumber...

```
Private Function GetNextSerialNumber() As String
    Dim RetVal As String
    Using cn As New OracleConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OracleCommand("Select Top 1 SerialNumber From SerialNumbers Where Used = False Order By SerialNumber;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        RetVal = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        cmd.CommandText = "Update SerialNumbers Set Used = True Where SerialNumber = @SN;"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SN", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = RetVal
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Comment: Oracle SQL does not have a `BOOLEAN` data type (that is a data type that only exists in PL/SQL); you'll need to use a `NUMBER` or `CHAR` data type instead. Oracle does not support the `TOP` keyword either; you'll need to use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` (if you are using a modern version) or filter on the `ROWNUM` pseudocolumn after ordering. Also, if you run multiple `GetNextSerialNumber` calls in parallel then you may end up duplicate values.

Comment: @MT0  Thank you for the corrections. The Boolean type actually comes up in intellisense `OracleDbType` from `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client`. That is why I said "Oracle's interpretation of Boolean". As you can tell I am unfamiliar with Oracle specific sql code. I do not have Oracle handy for testing.